# AES-GCM Hash sub key parameter in Intel's IPsec library

Tags: aes, gcm, ipsec

I am trying to use Intel's optimized AES-128-GCM implementation (from the Intel white paper “Fast Multi-buffer IPsec Implementations on Intel Architecture Processors”, you can find the code [here](https://github.com/lukego/intel-ipsec/tree/4d7b9efcd141b3274ea71f921914773cd77a0590/code)).

The [aesni_precomp_*](https://github.com/lukego/intel-ipsec/blob/4d7b9efcd141b3274ea71f921914773cd77a0590/code/gcm_defines.h#L137) functions take an argument described as the “Hash sub key”. I have researched the role of the “sub key” a bit but I can not fathom what value I should pass in as the “Hash sub key”.

How do I get this nebulous “Hash sub key”?

Comment: They are most likely referring to $H$ which is an all 0 block encrypted with AES using the current key

Comment: Yes I believe they are referring to H, but now I have a chicken and egg problem with regard to Intel's API: I need the subkey to encrypt but in order to derive the subkey I need to encrypt...

Comment: Could it be that they expect me to pass in the initial block, e.g. all zeroes in this case? After all a comment says: “H, the Hash sub key _input_.”

Comment: $H$ only requires AES to compute, and the functions you are sending it to are all GCM related, so you do not need those functions to compute $H$